# How can I pull out the specific attributes in os.stat?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Reffering to:

```py
os.stat_result(st_mode=33206, st_ino=562949953964059, st_dev=705631656, st_nlink=1, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_size=2499889, st_atime=1593127382, st_mtime=1592595491, st_ctime=1593122416)
```

I am trying to extract the time slots (st_atime, st_mtime, st_ctime) and put them into a list?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're just attributes, you can access them by name like any other attribute:

```
res = os.stat(...)
[res.st_atime, res.st_mtime, res.st_ctime]
```

or, since it's a namedtuple-like object, you can slice:

```
res[7:10]
```

I'd strongly recommend using the names though; the slice is using magic numbers that make it far less self-documenting. It is legal to rely on positive indices below 10, [per the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat_result):

> For backward compatibility, a `stat_result` instance is also accessible as a `tuple` of at least 10 integers giving the most important (and portable) members of the stat structure, in the order `st_mode, st_ino, st_dev, st_nlink, st_uid, st_gid, st_size, st_atime, st_mtime, st_ctime`. More items may be added at the end by some implementations.

Comment: Thanks man! Also, I found that I can pull them individually using  for example
mydata = os.stat('mytext.txt')
print(mydata.st_ctime)

but your method to pull the list using the last three attributes is perfect and way clearner. Thank you so much

The reason why i didn't think you could slice it because I did type(res) and it pulled class and I did not think it would pull a list.

Comment: @Ray: They've spent the last few releases converting most APIs that return raw `tuple`s to returning specialized `tuple`-like objects where elements of the `tuple` are accessible by name, not just position (and in cases like `stat_result`, it can have some values that are only accessible by name, not index, so the positional bits are portable, while the names are only available on systems that provide them).

Comment: @Ray: FYI, I rechecked the docs, and tweaked my answer slightly. Slicing to `[-3:]` isn't portable, because the `tuple` size might be greater than `10`. The only guaranteed safe slice would be `[7:10]` to ensure you start at the right offset and pull exactly three items, no more.

Comment: You call them tuple-like but they are actually tuples. It's right there in `os.stat_result.__bases__`.

Comment: @wim: It's not actually `tuple` itself, but yes, they're subclasses of `tuple`. In the case of stuff like `stat_result` though it's even weirder than simple `namedtuple` classes, because they're a [struct sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/tuple.html#struct-sequence-objects) that can do things you can't do at the Python layer at all (e.g. having additional immutable attributes that aren't iterated or indexable with the `tuple`-like behavior). So yes, `tuple` subclass. But sufficiently different that the uses go beyond  `tuple` or even `namedtuple` that people are used to.

Comment: @ShadowRanger thanks man! yeah that worked pretty good!